# UnpicklingError: could not find MARK in utils.file

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

I am facing this error:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 1334, in unpickle
    return _pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')

UnpicklingError: could not find MARK
```

while my `utils.py` code is:

```
with smart_open(fname, 'rb') as f:
    f.seek(0)
    # Because of loading from S3 load can't be used (missing readline in smart_open)
    if sys.version_info > (3, 0):
        return _pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
    else:
        return _pickle.loads(f.read())



def pickle(obj, fname, protocol=2):
    """Pickle object `obj` to file `fname`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    obj : object
        Any python object.
    fname : str
        Path to pickle file.
    protocol : int, optional
        Pickle protocol number, default is 2 to support compatible across python 2.x and 3.x.

    """
    with smart_open(fname, 'wb') as fout:  # 'b' for binary, needed on Windows
        _pickle.dump(obj, fout, protocol=protocol)
```

Anyone please help me I suffering on it few days.....

Comment: What is `smart_open`? Why is the `pickle` module named `_pickle`?

Comment: How is the file created?

Comment: Actually this is not my code, it's showing error in the python 27 scripts file i also not sure why the code like this..

Comment: Can i have you guy's email so i can send my code to you.. thank you very much im dying

Comment: How are you triggering this error? Please show the complete traceback.

Comment: Don't email it to us, just put the required code in the question.

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 1334, in unpickle
    return _pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')

UnpicklingError: could not find MARK <<< so its just showing the link of the code that i shown in the question.

Comment: But how are you executing this file?

Comment: I'm using pythin 2.7 to run the main file of the project and it coming out the error which in python27 file which is not under my knowledge.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lG6qRIdSA0 I'm actually doing this and keep follow exactly his instruction but error appearing everywhere now.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to load a model that was trained and saved in Python 3, but you're using Python 2. See

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/853

Comment: thankyou, i actually read about it still not clear what should i do. i already now changed to using python 3 in anaconda yet still facing same error, can i know the steps to solve it?

Comment: Where did the pickle file you're trying to load actually come from?  Can you post it here, or at least the first few bytes of it?  `open(<path_to_file>, 'rb').read(1000)` or something.  It could just be corrupt or malformatted somehow.

Comment: you mean these?  file=open(path2+'/conversation.json');
data = json.load(file)
cor=data["conversations"];
with open('conversation.pickle','w') as f:
    pickle.dump([vec_x,vec_y],f)

Comment: I don't know because that doesn't give me any context.  Is that your code, or someone else's?  Where are you running that code, and in what Python version?   I would also point out that there are different *protocol versions* for pickle files.  The code you quoted above says that it default to reading "version 2" pickles, which is the default on Python 2.  On Python 3 `pickle.dump()` uses newer pickle protocol versions.  So you need to make sure the file is being read and written with the same protocol version.

Comment: https://github.com/shreyans29/thesemicolon i got the code from here and im still a programming student so i'm still leak of python knowledge but have to build a chatbot so need your help so badly, thank you..!

Comment: i m running the code in python 3 and can i know how to diff the protocol version?

Comment: I see. I'll try to get back to you soon. On Python 2 the pickle protocol is version 2,but on Python 3 it's a bit trickier since it depends on the 3.X version. However, you can always work with a pickle protocol version from older Pythons in newer ones. So like, if you call `pickle.dump(obj, f, protocol=2)` it will write a file in protocol version 2,which seems to be the default ingested by gensim. I can't say for sure if that will help you but it might.

Comment: thank you ...! but im still not sure how to use it and hope to heard from you soon !!

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you.  Did you try what I wrote in the above comment?

Comment: Yes i did tried, and it jumped to another error in another file which named "old_saveload.py" , the error :     return _pickle.loads(file_bytes, encoding='latin1')

UnpicklingError: could not find MARK and the code:         if sys.version_info > (3, 0):
            
           return _pickle.loads(file_bytes, encoding='latin1')
        else:
            return _pickle.loads(file_bytes)

Comment: Could you update your question to specify *exactly* what you are doing, step-by-step?